# How to add learning rate to summaries?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

How do I monitor learning rate of AdamOptimizer?
In [TensorBoard: Visualizing Learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) is said that I need

> Collect these by attaching scalar_summary ops to the nodes that output the learning rate and loss respectively.

How can I do this?

Comment: But the learning rate of Adam is constant... Adam calculates some gradient statistics and changes step size based on the the learning rate and those statistics.

Comment: Yes, you're write, in fact I need the plot of the step size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like following inside the graph would work fine:

```
with tf.name_scope("learning_rate"):
    global_step = tf.Variable(0)
    decay_steps = 1000 # setup your decay step
    decay_rate = .95 # setup your decay rate
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.01, global_step, decay_steps, decay_rate, staircase=True, "learning_rate")
tf.scalar_summary('learning_rate', learning_rate)
```

(Of course to make it work, it'd require to `tf.merge_all_summaries()` and use `tf.train.SummaryWriter` to write the summaries to the log in the end)

Comment: Interesting answer, but it's not for ADAM, @zhongyukuang