# How to Add adam optimizer metric to tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

When I trained model for several epochs and want to retrain it again for more epochs. How would Adam optimizer work. will it initialize the time from t =0 or will it save the last time step?

a) The documentation in tensorflow shows the following calculations. Is there a away I can add these metrics to tensorboard.

```
t <- t + 1
lr_t <- learning_rate * sqrt(1 - beta2^t) / (1 - beta1^t)

m_t <- beta1 * m_{t-1} + (1 - beta1) * g
v_t <- beta2 * v_{t-1} + (1 - beta2) * g * g
variable <- variable - lr_t * m_t / (sqrt(v_t) + epsilon)
```

there are no answers for a few questions since a long time [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990476/getting-the-current-learning-rate-from-a-tf-train-adamoptimizer) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752053/how-to-add-learning-rate-to-summaries).

I am actually getting a problem with error rate when re-training the model from the last checkpoint and I was not sure what exactly is happening with Adam optimizer in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is a bit similar to this question I think: [Saving the state of the AdaGrad algorithm in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547198/saving-the-state-of-the-adagrad-algorithm-in-tensorflow)
If you save and reload the state of the optimizer it will continue, if you don't load the state of your optimizer after training it will simply start again!

Comment: Thanks . I will check this and let you know. is there a way we can add time, beta1 and beta2 to tensorboard?

Comment: And when I print train_step as shown in the link u have provided using sess.run. I get None for every iteration. Is there any mistake I am making.